# ssh-copy-id sh command not found

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to copy my ssh keys to my machine but whenever I run  `ssh-copy-id archie@localhost`  it gives that error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/archie/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
archie@localhost's password: 
zsh:1: command not found: sh
```

In the example it's localhost but when I try with another machine it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`sh` refers to `/bin/sh` which, depending on the distribution, is usually a symbolic link to `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash`. Try running the command `sh` in your terminal and if it returns an error, it means `/bin/sh` is not there. If you have `root` access to the system, you can fix this by running `ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`.

Comment: I already have that linked to /bin/dash

Comment: It seems you use `zsh` as default shell. Can I suggest trying the command with `bash` as your default shell?

Comment: tried that, same thing happens

Comment: What is the output of the command `ssh  archie@localhost 'echo $PATH'`?

Comment: My Path was broken fixed it and it works thanks a lot.

Comment: @EnesDoğan you should still have answered the question gmelis asked you, as per the broken path